# Why doesn't Stack Exchange open links in a new tab?

Tags: discussion, users, hyperlinks, stack-exchange

It's simple to add an attribute to a hyperlink as target="_blank" - but Stack Exchange prefers to open the website in the same tab.

Every time as a user, I need to take care to open in a new tab, so that I can keep browsing other answers. This is mostly problematic when some one quotes another link in an answer - so you have not yet finished reading up the solution, but would be interested to check out that link as well.

Any of you have experienced this?

Comment: I think it's a bit unfair to down vote this. While the question might seem like basics it also seems honestly asked and the author and others in the situation could learn from some good answers.

Comment: @edeverett - this is Meta. [It is different](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) from other sites, one difference is that voting can also indicate **disagreement**.

Comment: @Oded Fair enough then. I just followed a link from ux.se. Change of contexts clarified. (@vamshi4001 if you want fuller answers to your question you might want to re-post in ux.se but with make the question generic about all sites - I think there is valid UX question in there...)

Comment: @edeverett: closed as a duplicate now; the Jakob Nielsen quote there summarises my opinion on this behaviour nicely.

Answer (score 10):

It is simple.

And it takes the choice away from the user.

If the user does not wish to open the link in another tab, having `target="_blank"` there means that they don't have a choice — the link *will* open in another tab/window.

Most people know to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-click in order to open in a new tab, and many prefer to have this level of control.

Comment: Clicking the middle mouse button also opens a new tab.

Comment: And for people with a wheel mouse, who think they don't have a middle button: yes you do.

Comment: Why not a *setting*?

Comment: Because we strongly believe in sane defaults and in not having settings for every possible little thing. That way lies madness, @All

Comment: `> "Wrong currents are holding me... Beneath the surface of sanity..." - Evocation`