# Open "similar questions" links in a new tab

Tags: feature-request, hyperlinks, similar-questions

When I ask a question, a sidebar appears on the right suggesting me questions similar to mine. Often, halfway through writing a question, an interesting suggestion pops up and I want to quickly check whether that question has an answer that might help me and save a duplicate for the site.

I think that it would be more convenient if those links opened in a new tab, because often I want to just open the question, look at it, realize it's of no help, close it and return to writing my question, or maybe keep both open and compare the two. As it is right now, each time I click on one of those links my browser asks me if I'm sure that I want to leave the page, unless I right click and select "open in a new tab".

For example, on Physics SE there is an additional list, "questions that might already have your answer", that already opens link in a new tab and I find it much more convenient.

I know it's a minor issue and I might as well right click, but I wanted to ask whether other users feel it would be better this way.

EDIT: to make things more clear, I'm aware of the other instances of similar questions linked by Monica Cellio in the comments. My point was that, for example, on Stack Overflow, this feature is already implemented in this list

[image]

and in Physics SE in this list

[image: Physics list]

I'm not sure about other sites. It is convenient because one can quickly check the content of multiple question for comparison with their own, while the site wide "similar questions" list does not do that

Comment: Middle click also opens in a new tab. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard I use an Apple trackpad, no middle click :(

Comment: You can use Command and click then (or Control and click? not sure, please try both)

Comment: Command click works, thanks for the tip. Although, a bit strangely, while it opens the link in a new tab, it doesn't automatically visualize the new tab, but that might be browser dependent.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256390/162102 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/266372/162102 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/233684/162102 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/237745/162102 https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2275/162102

Comment: @MonicaCellio I'm asking specifically about the links in the "similar questions" list, not links in general. And anyway the other, pretty much identical, "questions that might already have your answer" list already has this feature - why are the two different?

Comment: I could only pick one duplicate, but requests to open certain links in new tabs have been made several times before and the result is always the same: we don't take choice away from the user.  You can open links in a new tab from your browser, but if SE pushed to a new tab a user couldn't override that.  I tried to pick the one with the most focused answer; do you think one of the others is a better fit?  We can change that.

Comment: Again, if taking away this choice from the user is so bad, why is this feature already implemented in the other list?

Comment: Oh, I missed that you're making a case for this specific situation despite all that precedent.  I suggest [edit]ing to link to the other question and then explain more clearly what the behavior is that you're seeing on Physics and why you think that's better.  (I'm not sure what links you're referring to there that automatically open in new tabs.)  Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're being ironic. I don't think I offended anyone, if so I'm sorry.

Comment: Oh, you mean the suggestions that appear as soon as you enter your title.  I was confused because clicking one of those *already* opens in a new tab (I just verified), so I thought you must mean something else.  No irony here; I'm trying to help you.

Comment: yes, my point was, if those open in a new tab, why don't the other suggestions? But I understand that this is not something SE wants to change and it's not a big effort to right click anyway.